# Where and how do I make another folder to put text files so they work when I export?

Tags: file-io, printwriter

I have a folder with my text files that can read and write and work in eclipse. But, when I export to jar, it fails because the files are not found, meaning they are not exported and I don't know how to make eclipse do that. I'm sure the solution is out there, but I don't know exactly what I'm searching for. Do I make a relative directory and how? Or another source folder? What exactly do I need to do?

This shows I have a folder called conf where my files are stored but it is not there on export.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("conf/Admins.txt"));        
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter("conf/CurrentUser.txt");

    int id = 0;
    String name = "";
    String pass = "";
    boolean found = false;
    while(in.hasNext()) {
        id = in.nextInt();
        name = in.next();
        pass = in.next();
        if(id == userID) {
            out.write(id + " " + name + " " + pass + "\n");             
            found = true;
            break;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was once exported, put my conf file in the same place as the exported jar file. I don't know if, theres a better way but this is a win for me.